# No puedo obtener los valores de un array por metodo del objeto inicializado

Tags: c++

Buenas saludos,
Tengo problemas con recuperar los valores almacenados en el array, el inconveniente esta en que no estoy seguro si `double Nota::getNotas()`y `void Nota::inicializa()`, esta correctas.

```
class Nota 
{
    public: 
        Nota();
        void iniciarAN(int Nalum, int Nntas);
        void inicializa(int array[], int idalum, int Nalum, int Nntas);
        double getNotas();
        int getAlumno();
        int getPromedio();
        int CalculaPromedio();
    private:
        int Notas[];
        int Nnotas; 
        int Nalumno; 
        int IDalumno;
        double promedio;
        int count;
};

Nota::Nota()
{ 
    Notas[20] =0;
    IDalumno = 0;
    promedio = 0;
    Nnotas = 0;
    Nalumno = 0;
}

// pone al objeto los valores recibidos como parámetro
void Nota::iniciarAN(int Nalum, int Nntas)
{ 
    Nnotas = Nalum;
    Nalumno = Nntas;
}

// pone al objeto los valores recibidos como parámetro
void Nota::inicializa(int array[], int idalum, int Nalum, int Nntas)
{
    Nnotas = Nalum;
    Nalumno = Nntas;
    Notas[Nntas] = array[Nntas];
    IDalumno = idalum;
}

// Regresa las notas
double Nota::getNotas()
{ 
    return Notas[Nnotas]; 
}

// Regresa la id del alumno
int Nota::getAlumno()
{
    return IDalumno;
}

// Regresa el promedio
int Nota::getPromedio()
{ 
    return promedio;
}

// Agrega cant a la cantidad de Notas en existencia
int Nota::CalculaPromedio()
{
    //promedio=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Nnotas; ++i)
    {
        promedio+=Notas[i];
    }
    return promedio;
}

#include <iostream>
#include "Nota.h"

using namespace std;

Nota lista[30], AN;
int alm, nts;

void ListarNotas()
{
    cout<<"La lista de articulos en el almacen es la siguiente"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t"<<"No"<<"\t"<<"ID Alumno"<<"\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < alm; i++)
        cout<<"Nota "<<i+1<<"\t";
    cout<<"Promedio"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < alm; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<i+1<<"\t"
        <<lista[i].getAlumno()<<"\t";
            for (int n = 0; n < nts; n++)
                cout<<lista[i].getNotas()<<"\t";
        cout<<lista[i].CalculaPromedio()<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    int opc, idalum, array[20];
    double pro;

    cout<<"Cantidad de Alumnos: ";
    cin>>alm;
    cout<<"Cantidad de Notas: ";
    cin>>nts;
    //AN.iniciarAN(alm,nts);
    for (int a = 0; a < alm; a++)
    {
        cout<<"Teclea el numero de identificacion del Alumno "<<a+1<<endl;
        cin>>idalum;
            for (int n = 0; n < nts; n++)
            {
                cout<<"Ingresa La Nota"<<n+1<<endl;
                cin>>array[n];
            }
        lista[a].inicializa(array, idalum, alm, nts); 
    }
    ListarNotas();
    return 0;
}
```

Resultados obtenidos.

```
Cantidad de Alumnos: 4
Cantidad de Notas: 3
Teclea el numero de identificacion del Alumno 1
1234
Ingresa La Nota1
12
Ingresa La Nota2
24
Ingresa La Nota3
20
Teclea el numero de identificacion del Alumno 2
10
Ingresa La Nota1
23
Ingresa La Nota2
24
Ingresa La Nota3
1
Teclea el numero de identificacion del Alumno 3
20
Ingresa La Nota1
12
Ingresa La Nota2
4
Ingresa La Nota3
5
Teclea el numero de identificacion del Alumno 4
21
Ingresa La Nota1
2
Ingresa La Nota2
3
Ingresa La Nota3
5
La lista de articulos en el almacen es la siguiente
        No      ID Alumno       Nota 1  Nota 2  Nota 3  Nota 4  Promedio
        1       1234    0       0       0       1241

        2       10      0       0       0       17

        3       20      0       0       0       27

        4       21      0       0       0       28


--------------------------------
Process exited after 23.83 seconds with return value 0
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: Deberías dejar sólo una etiqueta, o C# o C++, no ambas.

Comment: ¿Qué errores obtienes? ¿Es al compilar? ¿Al ejecutar? Podrías agregar esta información a tu pregunta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: si compila, no arroja error. solo que no me da los resultados esperados.

Answer (score 2):

Ok vamos allá...
Tienes algunos errores. El primer de ellos es que no puedes declarar un array en una clase **y no darle el tamaño en la hora de declararlo**. Si quieres darle el tamaño después, deberás usar memoria dinámica, un puntero e después definir el tamaño con new[] dentro del constructor. Algo como:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo{
public:
    Foo( const int TAM){ array = new int[TAM]; }
    ~Foo(){ delete[] array; }
private:
    int* array;
};

int main (){
    Foo bar(10);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Muy importante también es no olvidar de destruir con delete[] dentro del destructor. Otra solución es dar un tamaño fijo al instante de declararlo igual como lo harías en main.

La función `Nota::getNotas` se debe pasar el indice de la nota que quieres obtener:

```
int Nota::getNotas(**int i**) {
    return Notas[**i**];
}
```

Y a la hora de llamar lo haces pasando el valor del indice tal que:

```
for ( int n = 0; n < nts; n++ )
    cout << lista[i].getNotas(**n**) << "\t";
```

Otro erro que daba esa función es que devolvía un double pero lo correcto es que lo hagas retornar un int(El tipo del dato retornado). Luego si necesitas haces un cast.

Otro erro que vi fué esta linha:

```
Notas[Nntas] = array[Nntas];
```

No puedes copiar un array a otro, un array no es un objeto que contenga funciones miembro que te hagan ciertos trabajo, un array es apenas un conjunto de datos de un mismo tipo, si quieres copiarlo debes hacerlo vos o usar alguna función para ellos. una forma de copiar un array a otro puede ser esta:

```
std::copy(array, array+20, Notas);
```

Para usar esa función(copy) vc debe incluir . La función necesita que le digas el inicio del array a ser copiado(array), el final del array a ser copiado(array+20 que es el tamaño do array) y el inicio del array que va recibir los datos(Notas). Otra forma más simples es copiar uno a uno con un for.

El código completo te lo dejo [aquí](http://codepad.org/XtYn20PG).